# Install libsodium on macOS

Tags: c++, xcode, bash, macos, libsodium

I am trying to incorporate libsodium into my C++ project in Xcode. I am following the Installation instructions here: https://libsodium.gitbook.io/doc/installation

However, I'm not sure where the "installed" files go on my machine or how to then incorporate them in my Xcode project. The libsodium website is not helpful. Could someone help clarify for me please?

I have downloaded the latest stable release, unzipped it, and typed the following code into the shell:

```
./configure
make && make check
sudo make install
```

It seems that the configure, make and install processes go smoothly. I expected the next steps to link to Xcode would be clear, but they are not, and I am lost. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: brew install libsodium

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you perform the `sudo make install` step, the library files will be installed into the location the `./configure` step designated. By default, this is usually `/usr/local/lib`.

You will still need to add the library files to your XCode project.

Try reading [Link a target to libraries and frameworks](https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/10.2/#/dev51a648b07) about how to add the libsodium libraries. Pay attention to the "Add Other..." button which will allow you to navigate to the location you installed the libraries.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for telling me libraries by default end up in /usr/local/lib. I see many other libraries I have installed in there as well. Worked perfectly and really helped!